# What is a good alternative to Rackamole ? - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I would like to see realtime activity from the users of my webapp.

Like which page they are currently on, what links they clicked on, how many users are currently logged in, etc.

Anyone know of any good gems for Rails 3 for that functionality ?

Edit: An alternative to Rackamole (because Rackamole requires MongoDB and I am not running Mongo)

Answer (score 1):

http://mixpanel.com/ is another similar service.

Answer (score 0):

http://chartbeat.com/ is a service that does this using javascript.